# Check if possible to run command as sudo in Bourne shell?

Tags: shell, unix, sh

I'm writing a Bourne shell deployment script, which runs some commands as root and some as the current user. I want to not run all commands as root, and check upfront if the commands I'll need are available to root (to prevent aborted half-done deployments).

In order to do this, I want to make a function that checks if a command can be run as root. My idea was to do this:

```
sudo_command() {
    sudo sh -c 'type "$1"'
}
```

And then to use it like so:

```
required_sudo_commands="cp rm apt"
for command in $required_sudo_commands do
    sudo_command "$command" || (
        echo "missing required command: $command;
        exit 1;
    )
done
```

As you might guess by my question here: it doesn't work. Does any of you see what I'm doing wrong here?

I tried running the command inside sudo_command by itself, but that miraculously (to me) did work. But when I put the command into a separate file, it didn't work.

Comment: Under what circumstances do you expect a command to be available at all, but not to `root`?

Comment: I expect some commands to be available to `root` that are not available to the current user, so I check those separately. I prefer not checking everything as `root`, because I think it's a good habit to do the absolute minimum with `root` privileges.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two immediate problems:

1. The `$1` not expanding in single quotes.

   You can semi-fix this by expanding it in double quotes instead: `sudo sh -c "type '$1'"`
2. Your command not exiting. That's easily fixed by replacing your `|| (..)` with  `|| {..}`.

   `(..)` creates a subshell that limits the scope of everything inside it including `exit`. To group commands, use `{..}`

However, there is also the fundamental problem of trying to use `sh -c 'type "$1"` to do anything.

One of the major points of `sudo` is the ability to limit what a user can and can't do. You're assuming that a user has complete, unrestricted access to run arbitrary commands as root, and that any problems are due to `root` not having these commands available.

That may be a valid assumption for you, but you may want to instead run e.g. `sudo  apt --version` to get a better (but still incomplete) picture of whether you're allowed and able to run `apt` with `sudo` without requiring complete and unrestricted access.

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot, my script's a good bit further along now. The reason I check for the availability of commands, is that I want to ensure the script has a large chance of exiting before possible damaging-if-unsuccessful operations, because I don't know of ways to allow for perfect/lightweight rollback of arbitrary shell commands.

Comment: I ended up ripping out this code and running my script inside a Docker container, that way if I bork my environment during development I can just rebuild the container in under a minute.